# USB and Bitlocker

Tags: encryption, bitlocker

Is it possible to change my Bitlocker from USB encryption to password protected without the USB? The USB stick has to be installed.  I am finding that the USB is getting left in the computer so it doesn't really matter if I have Bitlocker on the computer.  This is a computer that is being used in a Dr. office so it would be much better to use a password encryption then the USB. I have turned off bitlocker and tried changing the settings but when I turn it back on it still prompts me for a USB.

Answer (score 1):

The exact procedure depends of the version of windows and whether you have a [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) chip in your system but it's doable by [following the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766295(v=ws.10).aspx).

There are better ways, however, to deal with this issue.

[Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/) once suggested linking hardware tokens with something that users take with them (he suggested to use them as key to the coffee machine). For instance, if your USB token is (physically) linked to your car keys, or with the badge used to unlock the door, then you're pretty sure it will be taken home when the user isn't present.

Another possible solution is to use [network automatic unlock](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/bitlocker/bitlocker-how-to-enable-network-unlock): the machine will pull the bitlocker key directly from your domain info at boot (you should still be able to use the recovery key if needed). Couple that with a sensible desktop session lock policy and you'll have a pretty robust system (I suggest you consider the use of a [bluetooth proximity desktop locker tool](http://btprox.sourceforge.net./) which are, in some environment, an excellent compromise between security and ergonomic).

**Edit:** I realized I didn't mention the most important part: when you enable bitlocker, you don't do that for the kicks. You do that to mitigate a specific risk. What that risk is is entirely dependent on your situation, of course but when I wrote my suggestion, I was assuming that you were thinking of the typical risk mitigated by full disk encryption. physical theft of the hard drive or machine. If that is not what you had in mind, please edit your question (or better yet, ask a new, more specific one. Please don't forget to explain what environment you're running as well).